# How to display just the arrow of <select>?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a down arrow of `<select>` without displaying any options. Only when the arrow gets clicked, the options will be displayed as usual.

Instead of this:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

An empty option is no solution because the size of the select tag is auto sized by the 'longest' option. Resizing the select-tag by 'width:20px' does not work in every browser. Only the arrow should displayed nothing else except the user clicks on the arrow the options should displayed.

Comment: Have you tried to create an 'empty' option and make that the selected one?

Comment: You can set the width to 20px... but then you will need some JS or jQuery to adjust the size when it open

Answer (score 1):

This will start with only the arrow and when you select an option it will appear by the arrow.

```html
 <select style="background:transparent; border:0px; padding:0px;">
 <option></option>
 <option>here is an option</option>
 <option>another option</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want I think you want. Next time, show us the code you have tried. We are not here to write your code. We are here to help you with your code.

```css
select {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option> </option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will not display **[just the down arrow](https://jsfiddle.net/6cw6ws95/)** with no padding/spacing to the left of the down arrow.

Comment: @hungerstar I changed it, I thought if it was empty is was good enough but now I got it that there is only a downarrow :)

Comment: Now you're missing the part where if an option is selected, it should display as usual.

Comment: @hungerstar If you click my link, it should work as usual.

Comment: Well if I click the link it works? which browser do you use?

Comment: I have. It doesn't. Try selecting _Option 1_. Does _Option 1_ appear in the select? No.

Comment: I see that is what u mean! well then or he needs to add Javascript or he just needs to do it like I did at first with an arrow with white space next to it.

Comment: @hungerstar that is not what the OP describes. Their example show that even-though the `latex` option is selected only the arrow shows.

Comment: *We are not here to write your code*  -  so don't!  By doing so, you open up the OP to asking more rubbish questions

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Do you want that all these Option1, Option2 etc again gets hide when clicked elsewhere on the screen?

```js
function clicked() {
document.getElementById("a").innerText="Option1";
document.getElementById("b").innerText="Option2";
document.getElementById("c").innerText="Option3";
document.getElementById("d").innerText="Option4";
}
```

```html
<select onclick="clicked()">
<option value="Option1" id="a"></option>
<option value="Option2" id="b"></option>
<option value="Option3" id="c"></option>
<option value="Option4" id="d"></option>
</select>
```